# Time Variable Integrator in Verilog

Tags: for-loop, verilog, numerical-integration

I’m trying to write up an integration module in Verilog that can vary the duration of the integration period. It is compiling without error, and the data registers for the signal do actually store the signal, but the integral bus remains at 0.

The integral is calculated in a for loop as shown below

```
for (i = 0; i < duration; i = i + 1) integral = integral + memory[i];
```

`integral` is initialised to 0 at every clock-cycle, and `duration` is the number of cycles over which to integrate the signal.
However, in all my testbenches, `integral` never assumes any value other than 0. I am not sure what exactly is happening? Help with troubleshooting would be appreciated.

The full code is here:

```
module VariableIntegrator  (
        input [15:0] x,
        input clk, reset,
        input [7:0] duration, interval,
        output reg [63:0] integral
    );

    reg [15:0] memory [31:0];
    reg [7:0] i;

    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin

            integral    <= 64'd0;
            memory[0]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[1]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[2]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[3]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[4]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[5]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[6]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[7]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[8]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[9]   <= 16'd0;
            memory[10]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[11]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[12]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[13]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[14]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[15]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[16]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[17]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[18]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[19]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[20]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[21]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[22]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[23]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[24]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[25]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[26]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[27]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[28]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[29]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[30]  <= 16'd0;
            memory[31]  <= 16'd0;

        end

        else begin

            memory[0]   <= x;
            memory[1]   <= memory[0];
            memory[2]   <= memory[1];
            memory[3]   <= memory[2];
            memory[4]   <= memory[3];
            memory[5]   <= memory[4];
            memory[6]   <= memory[5];
            memory[7]   <= memory[6];
            memory[8]   <= memory[7];
            memory[9]   <= memory[8];
            memory[10]  <= memory[9];
            memory[11]  <= memory[10];
            memory[12]  <= memory[11];
            memory[13]  <= memory[12];
            memory[14]  <= memory[13];
            memory[15]  <= memory[14];
            memory[16]  <= memory[15];
            memory[17]  <= memory[16];
            memory[18]  <= memory[17];
            memory[19]  <= memory[18];
            memory[20]  <= memory[19];
            memory[21]  <= memory[20];
            memory[22]  <= memory[21];
            memory[23]  <= memory[22];
            memory[24]  <= memory[23];
            memory[25]  <= memory[24];
            memory[26]  <= memory[25];
            memory[27]  <= memory[26];
            memory[28]  <= memory[27];
            memory[29]  <= memory[28];
            memory[30]  <= memory[29];
            memory[31]  <= memory[30];

            for (i=0; i < duration; i = i+1) begin
                integral <= integral + memory[i];
            end
            integral <= integral * interval;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Please post your testbench

Answer (score 1):

In your always block, the later assignment to "integral" will override the previous one in for-loop. Then "integral" won't be updated from "memory".

```
for (i=0; i < duration; i = i+1) begin
    integral <= integral + memory[i];
end
integral <= integral * interval
```

You may move the combinational part of "integral" to another always block like this:

```
reg [63:0] integral_next;
always @*
begin: blk1
    reg [7:0] i;
    integral_next = integral;  // Default
    for ( i=0; i<duration; i=i+1 ) begin
        integral_next = integral_next + memory[i];
    end
    integral_next = integral_next * interval;
end
```

Then replace the assignment to "integral" with:

```
integral <= integral_next;
```